# How to create a dynamic route with netlify's serverless function

Tags: mongodb, netlify

I'm using Netlify's serverless function with Mongo to create routes that a react app can access as rest api the endpoint.

Following mongo's documentation, https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/developing-web-application-netlify-serverless-functions-mongodb/, to create a route we can use netlify's CLI.

For example the command:

```
netlify functions:create --name get_movies
```

creates a javascript file in:

```
netlify/functions/get_movies.js
```

and to access the route it would be:

```
http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/get_movies
```

This is all well and good when the route is static. But how do I deal with a dynamic route?

For example, I want to have a route that takes a query parameter, movie_name:

```
http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/<movie_name>
```

Depending on the `movie_name` the response would be different. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally recommend using a framework like Express or Fastify with their AWS Lambda integration to achieve something like this, but if you wish to avoid increasing your dependency list, you can achieve it using the following:

1. Add the following to your `netlify.toml`. This is a [Netlify Redirect](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/).

```ini
[[redirects]]
  forcec = true
  from = "/movie/:name"
  status = 200
  to = "/.netlify/functions/get_movies/:name"
```

2. Inside the `get_movies.js` file, you can do something like:

```js
const movieName = event.rawUrl.substring(event.rawUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
```

That will give you the last segment of the URL (only if it doesn't end with `/`).

Then you can access the movie as `/movie/name`